# Spring - changing Content-type HTTP header

Tags: java, android, json, spring

I am communicating with a JSON API using Robospice. This is how I set the headers for a POST request:

```
mHttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
mHttpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
Log.d(Global.TAG, mHttpHeaders.toString());
```

The problem is that I get a header which looks like that: `{Content-Type=[application/json]}` where I need to send `Content-Type:application/json` (which seems to be the only header that my server accepts). I can't find any way to change it (tried with both `add()` and `setContentType()` methods), how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should try followings and it works for me. I'm using Spring rest template inside Robospice.

```
MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application", "json");
List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
acceptableMediaTypes.add(mediaType);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
```

Comment: It gives me `{Accept=[application/json]}` headers.

Comment: What is the response from your server?

Comment: It's 500 Internal Server Error but I've tried that request with `curl` to verify if its about the headers and that seems to be the reason (i.e. header formatting) why the server won't accept the request.

Comment: If it is HTTP 500 then it should be problem in server side and need to be fixed in server side code. I think the header is okay but can you send more code to see how you are making request entity. I guess you are making something wrong somewhere else as well.

Answer (score 1):

The output

```
{Content-Type=[application/json]}
```

you see in the `Log` statement is just the `String` returned by the `toString()` method, it's not the actual header sent. For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    System.out.println(headers);
}
```

prints

```
{Content-Type=[application/json]}
```

If you are using the `HttpClient` and `HttpRequestBase` (`HttpGet`, `HttpPost`, etc.) correctly, the header will be sent just fine.